# Finding out whether a DirectInput device supports XInput (with mingw/gcc)

Tags: c++, windows, directinput, xinput

I'm working on an input system,  wrapping DirectInput and XInput. Currently XInput devices are enumerated twice, once as XInput and once as DirectInput (since they support both).

How can I find out if a given DirectInput device also supports XInput? There is [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee417014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on the topic, but it requires wbemidl.h and wmsstd.h which aren't available in mingw/gcc (and for some reason I want to avoid msvc - probably by habit).

I don't think blacklisting device names/guids is a good solution, but is there a better one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wbemidl.h` and all the related headers are available from [`mingw-w64`](https://mingw-w64.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/mingw-w64/trunk/mingw-w64-headers/include) project, don't mind the `64`it also supports 32bit.

[`Here`](http://pcsx2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/plugins/LilyPad/DirectInput.cpp) is an example that implements `IsXInputDevice` without including `wmsstd.h`

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, now the only problem left seems to be the lack of __uuidof() in gcc.

Comment: Thats not implemented in MinGW I guess.

Comment: Well, I guess the uuid is supposed to be unique, so I've read it using __uuidof() with msvc and hardcoded the read value for gcc. Seems to work.